# python split dataframe based on multiple criteria in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to filter the df based on 2 criteria: where Name != jack and ignore all dates for jack where Date <= 2020-04-01

```
 # List of Tuples
df =       [ ('jack', 'Apples' , '2020-01-01') ,
             ('Riti', 'Mangos' , '2020-02-01') ,
             ('Aadi', 'Grapes' , '2020-03-01') ,
             ('jack', 'Oranges', '2020-04-01') ,
             ('Lucy', 'Mangos' , '2020-05-01') ,
             ('jack', 'Apples' , '2020-12-01')
              ]
#Create a DataFrame object
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Name' , 'Product', 'Date']) 
df1
```

Expected result being:

```
    Name    Product Date
0   Riti    Mangos  2020-02-01
1   Aadi    Grapes  2020-03-01
2   Lucy    Mangos  2020-05-01
3   jack    Apples  2020-12-01
```

Comment: Do you mean (Name != jack) or (ignore all dates for jack where date <= 2020-04-01)?

Comment: both criteria.  (Name != jack) AND (ignore all dates for jack where date <= 2020-04-01)

Comment: Then why is there jack in the 4th row?(index = 3)

Comment: date far jack is greater than 2020-04-01. this is valid

Comment: (FALSE AND TRUE) is FALSE..

Comment: I guess you mean 'AND' for datas, like apple and banana not condition 'and' right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boolean indexing` of multi condition

```
cond1 = df1['Name'] != 'jack'
cond2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']) > pd.Timestamp('2020-04-01')
df1[cond1 | cond2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
    Name    Product Date
0   Riti    Mangos  2020-02-01
1   Aadi    Grapes  2020-03-01
2   Lucy    Mangos  2020-05-01
3   jack    Apples  2020-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the below:

```
import pandas as pd
 # List of Tuples
df = [('jack', 'Apples' , '2020-01-01'), 
('Riti', 'Mangos' , '2020-02-01'),
('Aadi', 'Grapes' , '2020-03-01'),
('jack', 'Oranges', '2020-04-01'),
('Lucy', 'Mangos' , '2020-05-01'),
('jack', 'Apples' , '2020-12-01')
]
#Create a DataFrame object
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Name', 'Product', 'Date']) 

# Filtering for condition Name = !jack
df1 = df1[df1['Name'] != 'jack']

# Convert the date to datetime64
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Filter by specified date
filtered_df = df1.loc[(df1['Date'] <= '2020-04-01')]

# print the filtered result
print(filtered_df)
```